# SQL command not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, web

Hi am trying to update a table with the emails from another table using ids that match in both tables. I must be doing it wrong because i get these errors

```
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 10
Must declare the table variable "@ListofPropIDs".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the table variable "@ListofPropIDs"."
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails TABLE(UserEmail VARCHAR(100),IDs VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO         @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails 
    SELECT              UserId, Username
    FROM                aspnet_Users

    UPDATE          UserDetails
    SET             UserEmail = IN ( SELECT UserEmail from @ListofPropIDs)
    WHERE           UserIdn   = IN ( SELECT IDs from @ListofPropIDs)

GO
```

Comment: You `Must declare the table variable "@ListofPropIDs".`  You have not declared `the table variable "@ListofPropIDs".`

Comment: Check the data types in "UserDetails" tables. IS the UserEmail is Varchar and userid is Uniqueidentier...  Is the insert statement is working when u executed ?

Comment: Please don't rewrite your question to ask a new one.  First, spend half a second trying to figure it out on your own.  Next, use the "Ask Question" button to ask your new question.  But seriously, spend a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Fix your first INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO         @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails 
SELECT              Username, UserId
FROM                aspnet_Users


UPDATE          UD
SET             UserEmail = P.UserEmail 
FROM UserDetails AS UD
JOIN @ListOfUserIdsAndEmailsAS P
  ON P.IDs = UD.USerIdn
```

#### However if your getting an error saying that conversion error on the UserEmail, are you sure that UserEmail is VARCHAR on the UserDetails table?  Maybe you should post that table structure.

Comment: o yes i messed up i should have changed it but now i get this error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Comment: update your post with correct syntax and paste the error please.

Comment: THe conversion is on the uniqueidentifier of the ID's as the email is varchar(100)

Comment: i've updated my answer.... what is the data type of the Aspnet_users.UserEmail column?

Comment: in the aspnet_users? or the userDetails?  you need to verify both

Comment: Check the data types in "UserDetails" tables. IS the userid is Uniqueidentier... Is the insert statement is working when u executed ?

Comment: In aspnet_users the username(which is the email) is varchar(100) and id is uniqueIdentifier. in user detail id the id bit is uniqueidentifier and the email is varchar(100)

Comment: and what about the table `userDetails`?  that is where you are updating and it sounds like it is defined as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Comment: INSERT INTO         @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails 
    SELECT               Username,UserId
    FROM                aspnet_Users  Try this...

Comment: @Roshan is correct your insert is backwards.  will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The variables need switching 
from

```
DECLARE @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails TABLE( UserEmail nvarchar(256),IDs uniqueidentifier);
```

to this

```
DECLARE @ListOfUserIdsAndEmails TABLE(IDs uniqueidentifier, UserEmail nvarchar(256));
```

Comment: i think a check mark on mine and upvote on roshan for all the help.. please.

Comment: you click the little triangle above the number of votes, look to the left of each answer and you can up vote.